# How to opt out viewing doc files in Gmail through Google Docs?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

When I want to view a doc attachment in Gmail, I am automatically sent to  my Google Docs to view it. How to stop that and use a default viewer (Word, Foxit, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

To view the file on a desktop application you'll need to **download** the file first. At present there is no way to set the action of the *View* button within Gmail.

The closest thing to what you are describing (assuming you are using Google Chrome) would be to download the file, then right click on the downloads progress and select **Always open this file type**. Then whenever you click download on a `.doc` file, Chrome will download the file and automatically open it up in Word for you.